# How to find most predictable subset of input samples?

Tags: neural-networks, clustering

I have a ton (200,000+) input samples of which a large subset is useless, provides no advantage in prediction accuracy. Currently I'm clustering the samples using K-Means and then running a preliminary (quick) model training on each cluster, then select the cluster with the best evaluation accuracy & minimum loss for further, fine-tuned training, but I'm wondering if there's a better way of doing it?

Comment: Why do you say that a large part of the dataset is useless?

Comment: Samples are windows of stock prices. They contain patterns that are either well-formed technically, or just random sideways movement after which e.g. an unexpected news was released and even though the price spiked, the previous X prices are not indicative of that surge.

Comment: So the assumption is that there exists a subset of samples with well-formed patterns that are most accurately predictive

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to, for example, perform a PCA to detect outliers, exclude these observations and train your neural network on the remaining observations?

Or you could try to train a Partial Least Squares model to predict your output; it allows you to see for each observation, the correlation with the output, it allows you to detect outliers in relation to the output, to check which variables are mostly noise (irrelevant to the output), etc, so it could be useful to your case. Even if the PLS model's predictive ability didn't satisfy you in the end, you could use it to exclude outliers and to check if there are variables that are making the model worse (in the VIP plot), and you could adjust your dataset to train your neural network.